# PHP foreach inside variable

Tags: php, variables, foreach

How would I include a foreach function inside a variable. The code should explain what I mean.

```
$list = get_posts('post_type=services&numberposts=-1');
    foreach ($list as $post) :
        $title = $post->post_title; 


    $return = '<li>
                    <a href="#main_content_inner" onClick="slide(this); return false" rel="catalogue_sevices_page">'.$title.'</a>
                </li>';
                endforeach;
```

That is not quite correct. I am trying to make it so that $return displays all the posts from the type services in the format

So effectively I am after::

```
$list = get_posts('post_type=services&numberposts=-1');
    foreach ($list as $post) :
        $title = $post->post_title;
```

And therefore the output from $return should look something like this

```
<li><a href="#content1" onClick="slide(this); return false" rel="catalogue_sevices_page">Title 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#content2" onClick="slide(this); return false" rel="catalogue_sevices_page">Title 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#content3" onClick="slide(this); return false" rel="catalogue_sevices_page">Title 3</a></li>
```

Any ideas,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to use concatenation to store data in a variable with in foreach loop

```
 $return .= '<li>....
```

and then return the $return variable before foreach end

```
 return $return;
endforeach;
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply append with the `.=` operator.

```
$return = '';
$list = get_posts('post_type=services&numberposts=-1');
foreach ($list as $post) {
    $title = $post->post_title; 
    $return .= '<li>
                <a href="#main_content_inner" onClick="slide(this); return false" rel="catalogue_sevices_page">'.$title.'</a>
            </li>';
}
return $return;
```